# What is VideoCore MMU used for in Rasperry?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mmu

In RaspberryPI architecture (Broadcom BM2328 SoC), we can see that ARM core physical memory is mapped to VideoCore memory through a second MMU (the first maps ARM virtual to physical memory). What is the use of this configuration? Doesn't the use of 2 MMU's increase the latency?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate to ask this.